# when passing two parameters excel VBA telling me it expects an '='?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function:

```
Sub WordsToDate(col, endRow)
    ....
End Sub
```

And then when i am calling it like this:

```
Functions.WordsToDate(7, endRow)
```

(Functions is the module) it gives me the error:

```
Compile Error: Expected: =
```

It pops and tells me this when i try to leave the line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use parantheses when calling a Sub (you would use them if you were calling a function...)

Comment: @TimWilliams: That is a valid answer ;)

Comment: @Tim Either that or use `Call`... (*shudder*)

Comment: @Gaffi - why *(shudder)* at using `Call`?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I've had to debug/refactor someone else's code that used it for every Sub call. I never do, and don't know anyone else who does regularly, so that process made me go cross-eyed by the time I was done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gaffi. I've just been thinking lately of the best way to make it clear that I am calling another sub / function in my code. I used to write as modulename.function/subname, but that gets pretty ugly! I recently took to Call again, because that is clear. Anyway, just wanted to see your input.

Answer (score 0):

Is `Functions.WordsToDate(7, endRow)` in a cell on a sheet?  In that case, you need to enter `=Functions.WordsToDate(7, endRow)` instead.